RTTR convert instance to variant
I am using RTTR library to write a general logger class. To have a simple log function, I am holding instance at the class member. So far, it works when the instance is a class. But I cannot achieve converting basic types to string.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <rttr/registration>

struct MyStruct {
    int my_int;
    double my_double;
    std::string my_string;
};

RTTR_REGISTRATION {

rttr::registration::class_<MyStruct>("MyStruct")
    .property("my_int", &MyStruct::my_int)
    .property("my_double", &MyStruct::my_double)
    .property("my_string", &MyStruct::my_string)
;

} // RTTR_REGISTRATION

class RttrPrinter {
public:
    RttrPrinter(rttr::instance instance)
        : instance(instance)
    {
    }

    void print_struct() const
    {
        for (const rttr::property& property : instance.get_type().get_properties()) {
            const rttr::variant variant = property.get_value(instance);
            std::cout << " " << variant.to_string();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    void print_basic_type() const
    {
        if (const std::string* ptr = instance.try_convert<std::string>()) {
            std::cout << *ptr;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    rttr::instance instance;
};


int main()
{
    MyStruct my_struct {
        .my_int = 1,
        .my_double = 2.5,
        .my_string = "three",
    };
    int global_int = 5;

    RttrPrinter struct_printer(my_struct);
    RttrPrinter basic_type_printer(global_int);

    struct_printer.print_struct();
    basic_type_printer.print_basic_type();

    my_struct = MyStruct {
        .my_int = 11,
        .my_double = 12.5,
        .my_string = "thirteen",
    };
    global_int = 15;

    struct_printer.print_struct();
    basic_type_printer.print_basic_type();
}

Output:
 1 2.5 three

 11 12.5 thirteen


The following code gives a compile time error.
rttr::variant variant = instance;


rttr/detail/impl/argument_impl.h(65,19): static_assert failed: 'Don't use the argument class for forwarding an instance!'

It seems I need to use variant::to_string for successful conversions. Is there a way to create variant from instance without explicitly checking for all basic types?
